# Windows Phone 8.1 App Signing

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

We are working on a universal app developed with Apache Cordova 3.6. We want to distribute it via HockeyApp to our beta testers and need therefore need to sign it.

For Windows 8 / 8.1 Store Apps this is no problem because you can set the certificate to sign with in the project file. But is there an equivalent for Windows Phone 8.1 (set the certificate somewhere) or do we need to sign the app via the tools that ship with the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

most of your Problems will be Solved [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx).

You will need the set the Identity inside your Package.appmanifest corresponding to your Signing certificate.

```
  <Identity Name="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" Publisher="CERTIFICATE_STRING" Version="1.0.0.9" />
```

If you run into error 0x8007000B while signing you will find the correct **CERTIFICATE_STRING** in your Windows Event Log. Go to   <kbd>Computer Management</kbd> > <kbd>Event Viewer</kbd> > <kbd>Applications and Services Logs</kbd> > <kbd>Microsoft</kbd> > <kbd>Windows</kbd> > <kbd>AppxPackagingOM</kbd> > <kbd>Microsoft-Windows-AppxPackaging/Operational</kbd> > And then find your error. Inside the error description you will find your correct **CERTIFICATE_STRING**